# How to get the weighted average of a changing list of percentages

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently working on a personal project, it's aim is to delete files permanently. Each Deletion is represented by an `OperationVM`and the app keeps an `ObservableCollection` of `OperationVM`s in `App.Operations`.

Each operation has its own progress, what I am trying to do is to show the overall progress on the taskbar, but before I do that I need to find the weighted average of the individual Operations' Progress'. Each OperationVM has these properties that can be useful:

- `Progress` : `double` (from 0 to 100)
- `Bytes` : `long` (the total number of bytes of the file)
- `BytesComplete` : `long`

I use the `Bytes` property as each operation's weight and came up with this code:

```
var totalBytes = App.Operations.Sum(o => o.Bytes);
var bytesWritten = App.Operations.Sum(o => o.BytesComplete);
var overalProgress =  (double)bytesWritten / _totalBytes;
```

as well as this:

```
var totalBytes = App.Operations.Sum(o => o.Bytes);
var percentage = App.Operations.Sum(o =>
{
    var weight = (double)o.Bytes / totalBytes;
    return o.Progress * weight;
});
```

They both seem to work for fixed lists, but when an operation is complete, it's removed from `App.Operations` and this causes the overall progress to decrease. Let me demonstrate:

#### When there are two operations :

[image: Image 1:]

#### When one of them completes :

[image: Image 2:]

**Is that behavior okay? If not, what can I do about it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is regular because the task bar show average of progress-bars not only one of them.

at first time average between `97.9 and 50.5 is 74.2` but when of them is finished new value is `54.2` therefore progress is decreased

```
this.taskBarItemInfo1.ProgressValue = ((double)e.ProgressPercentage1 + (double)e.ProgressPercentage2)/2 / 100;
```

in another way its this

```
this.taskBarItemInfo1.ProgressValue = summbytes(downloaded) / all fullbites
```

Comment: Correct, but logically, when an operation is complete the progress should increase not decrease

Comment: @Encrypt0r there is two progress bar not one what happen when second progress is 90% ?

Comment: @Encrypt0r you should update the progress bar with previous count. one of them being 100% but not removed. in view its removed but in formula it should not be removed.

Comment: @Sinoheh Sorry, didn't quite understand your question. but you can watch this video for more clarification: https://youtu.be/6IezPxZs2U8

Comment: @Encrypt0r there is no problem in progress bar its worked correctly, do you want to progress increased after one finished?

Comment: @Sinoheh I think the progressbar should just continue and not decrease.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary you mean I should keep two lists?

Comment: @Encrypt0r if you want to continue and not decreased you must know all file sizes and make summery of all file then save sum of all downloaded bytes then calculate exact value. In this video everything is ok

Comment: @Encrypt0r the problem is that `totalBytes` and `bytesWritten` reduces because you remove those lists, you can remove those list but you should keep their values, (makes sense? :D )

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary it does, you mean I should take the completed operations account when calculating the overall progress. However this make things a bit complicated. Maybe I should just do as Sinoheh has written in his answer.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary However, if you think you have the time to help me, Rude Fox is open source and you can find it here: https://github.com/encrypt0r/RudeFox

Answer (score 2):

For other people with the same problem. As M.kazemAkhgary said, you have to take the old operations' bytes into account as well. So this is what I ended up with this code:

#### First Define three private fields:

```
long _totalBytes = 0;
long _bytesOfCompletedOperations = 0; // total bytes of operations that are completed and are removed from App.Operations
long _writtenBytes = 0;
```

#### Then handle App.Operation's collection changed event

```
(App.Operations as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged += Operations_Changed;
```

And define Operation_Changed

```
private void Operations_Changed(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (App.Operations.Count == 0)
    {
        _totalBytes = 0;
        _writtenBytes = 0;
        _bytesOfCompletedOperations = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.NewItems?.Count > 0)
            foreach (OperationVM item in e.NewItems)
                _totalBytes += item.Bytes;

        if (e.OldItems?.Count > 0)
            foreach (OperationVM item in e.OldItems)
                _bytesOfCompletedOperations += item.Bytes;
    }
}
```

#### Now you can Find the Overall progress

```
_writtenBytes = App.Operations.Sum(o => o.BytesComplete);
var overallProgres = (double)(_writtenBytes + _bytesOfCompletedOperations) / _totalBytes;
```

And the progressbar increases smoothly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate overall progress with total bytes and bytes written. Use this formula for overall progress shown.

var percentage = 100 - ((totalBytes - bytesWritten) / totalBytes) * 100

Comment: This formula has the same problem as mine: When an operation is complete and it's removed from the collection, the progress decreases, just like the two pictures I have linked above.

Comment: @Encrypt0r  when an operation complete its both total bytes and completed bytes removed. So, the the calculation of the overall progress will be showing correct result.